# C++ cast raw table to another table type

Tags: c++

I want to write class similar to the `std::array` from C++11. To do this I am
declaring a table of type `char` inside this class and later I would like to call
`placement new` on this table After that I would like to use table as if it was regular table of type `T` and here comes the trouble.

Generally variable like:

```
char tab[size];
```

Is of type `char(&)[size]` and if that's so I would like to use `reinterpret_cast` on this table to cast it to table of type, that I am in fact using, so more or less I would like my code to look like this:

```
char tab[sizeof(T)*size];
T tabT[size] = reinterpret_cast<T(&)[size]>(tab);
// more code using tabT
```

However in this context tab is seen as `char*` type. Reason, why I thought it could work is ability to write following template function

```
template <typename T, size_t size>
function(T(&table)[size]){
    //do stuff connected with table of type T and size size.
}
```

I know I could do this without this fancy magic here, but I just want to know, why it does not work.

So my question is: Is there a way to do the thing I want to do and is there any more elegant way to do mentioned job?

PS: I do not declare raw table of type T like : `T tab[size]`, because I wouldn't be able to create elements, where there is no constructor without
arguments.

Comment: Perhaps if you used the standard term "array" instead of "table" people would understand you more readily.

Comment: "I wouldn't be able to create elements, where there is no constructor without arguments.". `std"::array` deals with this just fine without resorting to a `char` buffer.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use C++11 and I do not know how exactly is std::array implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast doesn't really help you:

```
char tab[sizeof(T)*size];
T tabT[size] = reinterpret_cast<T(&)[size]>(tab);
```

Since arrays aren't copyable this code doesn't compile when instantiated. At the very least you'd need to use

```
T (&tabT)[size] = reinterpret_cast<T(&)[Size]>(tab);
```

However, I'd recommend not to store the uninitialized elements as `char` array to start with. Just use a `union` with a nested array:

```
template <typename T, int Size>
class array
{
    union Data {
        Data() {}
        T values[Size];
    } data;
public:
    array() { /* initialize the elements appropriately */ }
    ~array() { /* destroy the initialized elements */ }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I do not exactly understand how does union help me in this situation. To create instance of Data, then `T values[Size]` will need to be created either way, so what is the trick?

Comment: @DawidPi: The compiler won't construct the elements in `values`. You'll need to create them using placement new (and, obviously, manually call the destructor later).