# dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c++

My problem is strongly connected to the question I asked before:

[C++ cast raw table to another table type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622826/c-cast-raw-table-to-another-table-type/34623078?noredirect=1#comment56991975_34623078)

I have seen different posts of this warning on SO, but unfortunatelly they do not cover my problem.

in short I want to declare some space on stack and then use it as array of some type T, where T can be of any type (especially non-POD type) and I cannot use C++11.

declarations of both tables I attempted to use was:

```
char m_rawMemory[sizeof(T) * _size];
T(& m_tabT)[_size];
```

the proposed solution to solve my problem was to do:

```
union Data {
    Data() {}
    T values[Size];
} data;
```

And it would be great if not the case, that I cannot use C++11 as my compiler does not support unrestricted unions (program for embedded environment) so types different than POD will simply not compile.

So I decided to create char table and use it in following manner:

```
m_tabT(reinterpret_cast<T(&)[_size]>(m_rawMemory)
```

this compiles, but gives warning given in a title. So my questions are:

Why do I get this warning?
How to do this properly?

Comment: I think there are plenty of resources explaining the problems with breaking strict-aliasing rules. Reading your earlier question, it seems to me instead of mimic'ing `array`, you could just use `vector`, passing in an allocator that returns a pointer to your "stack" allocated memory.

Comment: Aliasing rules means the type you reinterpret to can have different (stricter) alignment rules and trigger hardware exception. Try `reinterpret_cast`ing it the other way, from `T[]` to `char*`.